# How to check the Authentication Token against the serial number and passTypeIdentifier before sending data to database

Tags: rest, authentication, passbook

I create a pass for passbook. I also have a web server by using MAMP and database with 3 tabes such devices, registration, and pass_name. When I register device and pass, i need to check Authentication Token and serial number. What is the result of this checking and how can we check ?

Comment: You decide - you actually don't have to check anything if you don't want to, but if you don't there is a huge security risk that anyone could retrieve a pass from your server that they are not authorised to have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further to my comment - your process should be something like:

- create a pass and store `authenticationToken`, `passTypeIdentifier` and `serialNumber` and any other data about the pass that you would like to store in your pass_name table, also include a `lastUpdated` tag.
- install the pass - device registers and provides `authenticationToken` (in header), `passTypeIdentifier`,  `serialNumber` and `deviceLibraryIdentifier` (in the URL), and  `pushToken` (in POST body).
- check that your pass_table contains a record matching `authenticationToken`, `passTypeIdentifier` and `serialNumber` provided by the device
- if there is no record, return a `401 Unauthorized` response, else
- in your devices table, create a record with a key of `deviceLibraryIdentifier-serialNumber` and fields `deviceLibraryIdentifier`, `pushToken`, `serialNumber`, `passTypeIdentifier` and `authenticationToken` and return a `201` response.

Your `authenticationToken` should be unique to each pass that you issue.

You need to add `serialNumber`, `deviceLibraryIdentifier`, `passTypeIdentifier` and `authenticationToken` to your devices table so that your web service can locate the device record when you want to push an update and to respons to other requests as detailed in the [Passbook web service specification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011988)